# For any entry in Active Directory does the DistinguishedName ever changes?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, distinguishedname

Let's say a group is created with one name. If the group is subsequently renamed, does its distinguishedName also change?

I'm looking for a way to permanently track AD objects even if their display names or other properties change.

If distinguishedName is not constant, is there something else that is?

I've seen objectguid but that seems to be a byte[] generated from distinguishedName. Is that wrong and guaranteed unique and constant for the entire AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because objects can be moved from OU to OU. Try "uniqueIdentifier" instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680516%28VS.85%29.aspx